# Replacing all subsequent characters of a string, after matching a substring

Tags: java, string, replace, substring, character

I try to replace a character and all it's following characters within a string with another character.

This is my code so far.

```
String name = "Peter Pan";
name = name.replace("er", "abc");
Log.d("Name", name)
```

the result should be: "Petabc"

I would highly appreciate any help on this matter!

Comment: `replace()` will only replace what you passed by parameter, in your case, 'er'.

Comment: If the result should be **Petabc** then what does your code output for **name.replace("er" , "abc")**?? Whats debugging giving you?

Comment: @ShayHaned debugging gives out "Petabc Pan"

Comment: Do you expect **Pan** to be removed from the sequence after the replacement happens?

Comment: @ShayHaned yes, that is what I intend to achieve, however I am aware that only replace will not do that for me.

Comment: @LoveCoding You could use a regex expression to replace everything starting from "er" by "abc'".

Comment: This does the trick: `name = name.contains("er") ? name.replace(name.substring(name.indexOf("er")), "abc") : name`

Comment: Add these 2 lines to your code after the **replace()** execution **int index = name.lastIndexOf("abc");** and **if(index != -1) name = name.substring( 0 , index + "abc".length() )**;

Comment: @ShayHaned this logic actually worked. Thank you! :)

Comment: @RobinTopper unfortunately, your suggestion didn't really work for me.

Answer (score 1):

A way to achive your goal:

- search the string for the first appearance of the sequnce you want to replace
- use that index and cut the string using String#substring
- add your replace sequence to the end of the substring you just created

fin.

Good luck.

EDIT

In code it might look like this (not tested)

```
public static String customReplace(String input, String replace)
{
int index = input.indexOf(replace);

if(index >= 0)
{
    return input.substring(index) + replace; //cutting string down to the required part and adding the replace
}
else
    return null; //String 'input' doesn't contain String 'replace'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression here with `String`'s built-in `replaceAll` method to very easily do what you want:

```
original.replaceFirst(toReplace + ".*", replaceWith);
```

For example:

```
String original = "testing 123";
String toReplace = "ing";
String replaceWith = "er";
String replaced = original.replaceFirst(toReplace + ".*", replaceWith);
```

After the above, `replaced` will be set to `"tester"`.